# Maven mulit-module dependencies, - package does not exist (maven plugin classloader)

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I have a multi module maven project with the following setup.

```
/root/pom.xml
/root/core/proj1/pom.xml
/root/core/proj2/pom.xml
/root/support
/root/support/proj3/pom.xml
```

Parent pom is as follows (including only the relevant parts)

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>platform</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>platform-parent</name>

<modules>
    <module>support/proj3-service</module>
    <module>core/proj1-service</module>
    <module>core/proj2-service</module>
</modules>
```

proj1/pom.xml is as follows,

```
<artifactId>proj1</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

proj2/pom.xml is as follows,

```
<artifactId>proj2</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Now, in proj3/pom.xml, im adding proj1 and proj2 as dependencies,

```
<artifactId>proj3</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>proj1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>proj2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
       ...
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
```

The plugin in project 3 wants to query classes belonging to proj1 and proj2.

As per the plugin classloader documentation,
Please note that the plugin classloader does neither contain the dependencies of the current project nor its build output.
When a build plugin is executed, the thread's context classloader is set to the plugin classloader.

is there a way to make the plugin classloader aware of the other modules?

Comment: Can you post the full error output...

Comment: @khmarbaise edited

Comment: You should take a deeper look into the module which is mentioned in the error message: `on project docs-generation: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)`...Apart from that. This is not the full error output...there is much more...which gives good hints..

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for the hint here. i was so fixated on issue with the way i was setting up a multi module project. i have updated the question.

Comment: Which plugin is this? 
As for "As per the plugin classloader documentation, Please note that the plugin classloader does neither contain the dependencies of the current project nor its build output" 
It depends, a lot on the plugin implementation on how you can make it aware of other classes

Comment: Hi did you actually make a maven install (locally) before build ?

Comment: Either you don't ask clearly your question (due to a misunderstanding of you real problem?) and/or I miss something but what you try to achieve seems to be really basic in maven (a maven project with several modules, one of them depends on others). Moreover I don't get why you added the suffix `-service` to your modules, it doesn't make much sense to me and is probably one of the root causes.

Comment: There's way to resolve the paths to all the dependencies so you can add all the dependencies to your classloader via the `org.eclipse.aether` package.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `modules` tag of the parent pom.
Instead of :

```
<modules>
    <module>support/proj3-service</module>
    <module>core/proj1-service</module>
    <module>core/proj2-service</module>
</modules>
```

It should be :

```
<modules>
    <module>support/proj3</module>
    <module>core/proj1</module>
    <module>core/proj2</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: maven figures that out. take a look at maven reactor mechanism. it is part of maven core. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Comment: Did you atleast try what I suggested ?  The maven reactor is responsible to figure out the build order by determining the dependencies between the modules, but you have to specify correctly where to find the modules in the first place. Based on the directory structure you have mentioned in your question, there are no folders with the name `proj3-service`, `proj2-service` etc. Hence the maven reactor will not be able to find your modules and the build will fail. If not already done, try once what I have suggested and lets us know the outcome.

Comment: i already did. the problem is with plugin classloader unable to query the depedencies jars.

Comment: Ok. Can you provide the error log and the plugin code in your 3rd project's pom.xml.

Comment: the plugin classloader cannot load classes from the project dependencies. take a look at how maven abstracts classloader tasks among different maven components. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Class+Loading.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add additional .jars for maven plugins to use/see, you can add dependencies to plugins.

Something like that:

```
<build><plugins><plugin>
<!-- other plugin option -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin></plugins></build>
```